# C++ having reference for local variables

Tags: c++, reference

Is there any difference in the following two?

```
const int64 x = some_struct.x;

const int64& x = some_struct.x;
```

Is one better than the other? I have recently seen the reference being used somewhere but could not understand why someone would do that.

Comment: @JamesRoot Why would you mark that as a duplicate? My question was mainly towards if the reference makes any sense to PODs. I searched around and could not find any questions. If you find something please post it and mark it as duplicate.

Comment: You would have to ask the original programmer. There's no obvious reason.

Comment: @Undivided That's really weird. I was going to mark it a duplicate and decided that it wasn't, so I just let it be. I don't know why it marked it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think reference as an alias of the original variable.

```
some_struct.x = 1;
const int64 x1 = some_struct.x;
const int64& x2 = some_struct.x;
std::cout << x1 << "," << x2 << std::endl; // should be "1,1"

some_struct.x = 2;
std::cout << x1 << "," << x2 << std::endl; // should be "1,2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case is a copy of the value from `some_struct.x` while the second is still tied to it. So if `some_struct.x` changes its value, `x` will not be affected, but `&x` will refer to the change.

There is no `better` because this depends on the intention of the code where this is used.

Comment: If I do not intent to change the value of some_struct.x, does compiler do any optimizations in case of a reference?

Comment: I would guess that, if `some_struct.x` doesn't change, and the compiler can deduce that, then the code would be the same. If some_struct is passed around, it may be that the compiler needs to generate additional load instruction, if it can not infer that it hasn't changed.

Comment: @Undivided: In this specific example, probably not. But as soon as you write `const int& x1 = some_ptr->x;` then it's likely. The subtle difference is that `some_ptr` might change. If you know the pointer doesn't change, but the compiler is unsure, the reference could be an optimization.